# Making an iterative way to add GIST indexes to spatial tables

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am attempting to make a generic way to add GIST indexes to my postgres/postgis databank. The problem is that some tables have already a GIST index so I would like to ignore those. I might make a new database in the future so I would like to make this as generic as possible so I am using the structural tables.. I am making use of the Do block but I don't see why the system doesn't want to proceed.

I get a very unspecific error and I don't know how to proceed.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
  table_name text;
BEGIN 
    FOR table_name IN (SELECT f_table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE geometry_columns where not(f_table_name ilike '%view%') and not(f_geometry_column ilike '%st_union%') LOOP
        BEGIN;
            EXECUTE format('CREATE INDEX "gist_%I" ON %I USING GIST (geom);', table_name || '_index', table_name);
        EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
            RAISE notice  'Error occurred creating index for table %: %', table_name, SQLERRM;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

> SQL Error [25P02]: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
> Error position: line: 1 pos: 1

Comment: Well, `information_schema.tables` has no column named `f_table_name` or  `f_geometry_column ` to begin with.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241599/how-can-i-find-postgis-tables-that-are-missing-indexes

Comment: Additionally, your where clause `WHERE geometry_columns where ...` syntactically invalid. `Where` can only appear once in a select, whether it be the main query or a sub-query.